# Using .c source files with Rust

Tags: rust

Is there a standard way to include .c source files?

So far I've been using `extern "C" { ... }` to expose the functions, compiling .c to an object file, running rustc until ld chokes with an undefined reference, and using the arguments shown after `error: linking with 'cc' failed with code 1; note: cc arguments: ...` to run `cc myobjfile.o ...`

Answer (score 7):

> Editor's note: This answer predates Rust 1.0 and is no longer applicable.

Luqman gave a hint on IRC; using `extern "C" { ... }` with `#[link_args="src/source.c"];` in the crate file works for me.

Comment: That's clever. I've never seen anyone do that before, and would not necessarily expect this to continue working forever. This works because Rust uses a C compiler (currently always either gcc or clang) to drive the final link step.

Comment: (I would expect it to stop working in the relatively near future, at this point)

Answer (score 6):

Use the [cc crate](https://crates.io/crates/cc) in a build script to compile the C files into a static library and then link the static library to your Rust program:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "calling-c"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["An Devloper <an.devloper@example.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[build-dependencies]
cc = "1.0.28"
```

**build.rs**

```
use cc;

fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("src/example.c")
        .compile("foo");
}
```

**src/example.c**

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t testing(uint8_t i) {
  return i * 2;
}
```

**src/main.rs**

```
extern "C" {
    fn testing(x: u8) -> u8;
}

fn main() {
    let a = unsafe { testing(21) };
    println!("a = {}", a);
}
```