# Using multiple .c source files with Rust

Tags: rust

I am successfully using a `.c` file with Rust ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488425/using-c-source-files-with-rust)). How can I link multiple `.c` files? I've already tried `#![link_args="/c_src/*.c"]` with no luck.

```
- rust-demo
  - src
    - c_src
      - file1.c
      - file2.c
      - etc...
    - main.rs
```

Edit:

I think a better question would be, how can I simply drop the C source code in my Rust directory and start using it directly by using Rust's `link` attribute & `extern` (or any other way) with the above example in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I simply drop the C source code in my Rust directory and start using it directly by using Rust's `link` attribute & `extern` (or any other way)

You can't just put C code into Rust sources and expect it to work. As said in the comments of your other question, the syntax `#![link_args="foo.c"]` has never be planned to work, and you should not rely on that.

The only thing Rust code can be linked against (except other rust code) is a compiled library (static or dynamic). You need to compile your C files into one or several libraries before being able to call them from your Rust code.

The proper way to do so is adding a `build` argument in the `[package]` section of your `Cargo.toml`, you can thus invoke a makefile that will first build your C files into a static library, and then link your Rust code against it.

All details are provided on the cargo website : http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Cargo, add some sort of script with `build = ["gcc ..."]` to build them into a proper library, then you only have one thing to specify in `#[link_args]`

Comment: Yes, I am using Cargo. _add some sort of script with `build = ["gcc ..."]` to.._ Could you be a bit more specific please? Also, is this documented anywhere?

Comment: On the cargo website : http://crates.io/native-build.html

Comment: @goo, you can fine info on how to build non-Rust dependencies [here](http://crates.io/native-build.html).