# How do you deal with C macros when doing FFI from Rust?

Tags: c, rust, macros, ffi

I'm building a crate which is essentially a wrapper around the Xen C libraries for VM introspection. I used bindgen to make my bindings, and so far it worked well, but I'm facing an issue since bindgen doesn't expand C macros.

I need to port the following Xen API C code to Rust

```c
#include <xen/io/ring.h>

//returns address of the shared buffer in Dom0
vm_event_sring_t* ring_page = (vm_event_sring_t*)

// init the ring
vm_event_back_ring_t back_ring;
SHARED_RING_INIT(ring_page);`
BACK_RING_INIT(&back_ring, ring_page, XC_PAGE_SIZE);
```

The problem is that `vm_event_sring_t` and `vm_event_back_ring_t` are C structs defined dynamically during the preprocessing, by the `DEFINE_RING_TYPES` macro.

The macro is called in `vm_event.h` to define the types.

The same goes for `SHARED_RING_INIT` and `BACK_RING_INIT`, also defined as macros.

How can I deal with this in my Rust FFI crate?

Comment: Macros are a compile-time concept.  When you compile the C library, it will have automatically expanded the macros already.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think the OP's problem is that *consumers* of the library are expected to call the library's macro in their own code, which then generates new types / functions in the client code.

Comment: You will need to either re-implement the macros from scratch in Rust, or possibly write a small amount of C code that calls the macros as you need them, then compile and link that C code **plus** the library into your Rust code. See [Using .c source files with Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914680/155423) for an example of that.